# How do I export every key of a map in Sass?

Tags: sass, css-loader

I have this map

```scss
$colors: (
  black: $black,
  blue1: $blue1,
  blue2: $blue2,
  blue3: $blue3,
  blue4: $blue4,
  blue5: $blue5,
  blue6: $blue6,
  coral1: $coral1,
  coral2: $coral2,
  coral3: $coral3,
  coral4: $coral4,
  coral5: $coral5,
  green1: $green1,
  green2: $green2,
  green3: $green3,
  grey1: $grey1,
  grey2: $grey2,
  grey3: $grey3,
  grey4: $grey4,
  grey5: $grey5,
  grey6: $grey6,
  orange1: $orange1,
  orange2: $orange2,
  red1: $red1,
  red2: $red2,
  red3: $red3,
  saffron2: $saffron2,
  transparent: $transparent,
  white: $white,
);
```

And I want to export every key of it, like:

```scss
 :export {
    @each $name, $color in $colors {
      name: $name
    }
  }
```

What I get after importing it is an object with only the last key of the map, why is that? I want the object to be filled with every key

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't ask me why but apparently putting the key in an interpolation made it to work as intented

```scss
:export {
    @each $name, $color in $colors {
      #{$name}: $name
    }
  }
```

Now I get the full object